# Solution to PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, heat-equation

We have the following PDE:

$\frac{\partial W}{\partial \tau}=0.5\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial x^2}$

We are going to look at a special solution of the from:

$W(\tau,x)=\tau^af((x-c)/\tau^b)$      where c is an arbitrary constant.

Substituting the solution we get:

$\tau^{a-1}(af-b\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu})=0.5\sigma^2\tau^{a-2b}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \mu^2}$

where $\mu=(x-c)/\tau^b$

Now the part that I don't understand is why we can have a solution only if

$a-1=a-2b$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you can clear in the following way:
\begin{align*}
\frac{af-b\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu}}{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \mu^2}} = \frac{0.5\sigma^2\tau^{a-2b}}{\tau^{a-1}}.
\end{align*}

Then the only way that the equality is fulfilled is that they are equal to a constant (since the left only depends on $\mu$, and the right side only depends on $\tau$), then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{af-b\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu}}{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \mu^2}} = \frac{0.5\sigma^2\tau^{a-2b}}{\tau^{a-1}} =\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \tau^{2b-1}=\frac{\lambda}{0.5\sigma^2}.
\end{align*}
But this would say that the variable tao is a specific value, and so $W$ is a function of one variable, which is a contradiction.